# How to Export Email "Sent" Folder?

Tags: email

A client had her web site and email hosted at "company A". She was switching to "company B" but didn't want to lose her email.  I set up a Gmail account, POPed into her webmail account, and pulled the entire inbox into Gmail (for later transfer to her new host).

But I forgot about the "sent" folder.  Although the hosting plan is still up and running, she changed her domain record to point to the new host.  So I can't access the old webmail account via POP or IMAP because the email address needed for authentication now resolves to the new host.

Is there any way I can get the contents of the sent folder without having to do a "forward" one message at a time (there are hundreds)?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this through webmail? Seems like it'd be easier to do a quick POP/IMAP setup in Thunderbird(or whatever) and grab the messages that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While in most cases you'd normally access your webmail via something like webmail.yourdomain.com, I'm assuming this is what you say is no longer possible because the domain's been pointed elsewhere.

But, many hosts also allow webmail access through a more centralized system, eg. webmail.hostingcompany.com, which the other is just sort of an alias to. If that's the case(you'll need to talk to them, since you don't specify who it is) and the old mail account is still set up, there's a chance you can get in that way.

Besides that, depending upon how their directories or permissions are set up, you might be able to just grab the [mbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) files directly. There's a bit less of a chance on this one, but it's worth checking out.

Comment: I *can* still get in via webmail, using the temporary domain name they provided when we first set up the hosting plan.  So I can login and *see* the messages sitting in the "sent" folder.  But the webmail access address is like "servername.com:20082/3rdparty/squirrelmail/src/webmail.php" which works OK in a browser, but I can't put that in as the server name for POP/IMAP access in Thunderbird.